Best way to correct this shower drain?
During Covid I had this shower redone. The tile guy and the plumber were not on the same page when it came to the drain and I've lived with it like this for years. What's the best way to correct this and have a functional drain with cover?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Could you get us a better picture. Maybe one that truly indicates the height of the drain in relation to the tile.

Here are some ideas.  None of these is a great idea. They are in the order I would try them if I were in your situation, but don't take that to mean the order applies to you.

Get a squeegee mop and wipe down the floor after each shower.  Wait a minute to let the water drain off the walls, then do it.  This will remove the puddle and have the added benefit of reducing the amount of calcium deposit on the black floor.
Aside from the bad slope, if it was done properly the drain should have holes in the side of it, surrounded by gravel, just beneath floor level and above the waterproofing.  This allows water to drain if it gets through the grout.   If that was done, you could drill some holes in the grout just outside the drain to let water drain that way.  These holes will need maintenance, they'll clog easily.  Use a drill stop to make 100% sure you don't go to far.  Maybe just use a knife. :)
Add a layer of floor tile over top of the existing one, properly sloped and designed to accept a shower drain grate, perhaps with a frame to hold it, but otherwise draining into the existing drain. Use a lighter color tile so it doesn't show the scale as much.
Rip it all out and do it properly.

I'm not sure what you mean about the "same page".   The drain's height should be adjustable and the tiler should have adjusted it during his planning stage.    The only thing the plumber could do wrong in that regard is install the rough-in so high that it's impossible to slope the floor correctly, but in that case the tiler should have stopped work.  Even then, you could just buy a drain with a lower profile.  I blame the tiler.
